# How to query graphql endpint from a class based react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

The Load product is maybe we call it hook whose purpose of the life is fetch the data from a graphql backend

Here  its how LOAD_PRODUCT LOOKS LIKE

```
import { gql } from '@apollo/client'

export const LOAD_PRODUCTS = gql`
    query{
        categories {
            name
            products {
              id,
              name,
              inStock,
              gallery,
              category
            }
          }
    }
`

import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { useQuery,gql } from '@apollo/client'
import { LOAD_PRODUCTS } from '../../graphql/productAction'
export class ProductListing extends Component {

  constructor(){
    super();
    const {error,loading,data} = useQuery()

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>ProductListing</div>
    )
  }
}

export default ProductListing
```

for now i just want to fire the load user hook and save set the data to the different state there must be a method to do this i search on google but nothing help i just cant use fetch method to get the result

Comment: React hooks can't be used in class based components. The easiest way to solve this is to not use a class based component. Why do you want to use a class based component? Are you locked into an old react version? If you can't do that for whatever reason you will need to use the deprecated [`Query`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/components#query) component or the [HOC](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/hoc) depending on the use case. Also never perform async tasks like fetching remote data in the constructor.

Comment: I am in test and functional components are restricted i am facing a lot of difficulties even doing small task just getting the parameters from the url

Comment: by the way i have figured how to query i did it just using simple javascript fetch api

Comment: Okay, but that makes absolutely no sense. Fetching from remote endpoints in the constructor is a huge anti-pattern and all testing can also be done just with functional components. Testing component internals is discouraged anyways. Class based components are a legacy feature, nobody uses it anymore in new projects. You don't do yourself a favor if you keep using them just so you can unit test some internals, which shouldn't be done anyways. Also why would you use plain fetch with apollo? This is re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: @trixn i did try apollo but the problem with that i can not use hook inside a class based compoenent so i am bit disappointed and a kind of pissed of  Its an interview question i had to do everything using class based component

Comment: I see, but apollo provides components for querying data. I linked them in my first comment. So you do not need to use the `useQuery` hook, you can also render the `Query` component or use the `HOC` to connect your component and let the `HOC` inject the relevant props. This would be the correct way to use apollo with class based components. I can create an example for you if you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also query a graphql endpoint using the [Query](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/components/#query) component or the [HOC](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/hoc). But note that since class based components are considered legacy those do not receive any updates anymore.

**Using the Query component:**

```
import { Query } from '@apollo/client/react/components';

export class ProductListing extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Query query={LOAD_PRODUCTS}>
          {({data}) => <div>Render data here ...</div>}
      </Query>
    )
  }
}
```

**Using the HOC:**

```
import { graphql } from '@apollo/client/react/hoc';

class ProductListing extends Component {

  render() {
    const data = this.props.data;

    return <div>Render data here ...</div>;
  }
}

export default graphql(LOAD_PRODUCTS)(ProductListing);
```